# PHP query response to populate HTML dropdown (loop thru 2D array)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, multidimensional-array

I am getting exactly what I need from my PHP code and query; except I am having a really difficult time brining that data up to the front-end in order to populate an HTML dropdown.

Here is what I have on the PHP side; all working fine

```
$app->get('/dlteopt', function ($request, $response, $args) {   
        
    $which = $_GET['id'];


    if ($which) {

        if ($which == 'table_1'){
            $sql = "SELECT item1 FROM daya.blahblah";
        } else if ($which == 'table_2'){
            $sql = "SELECT item2 FROM daya.blahblah2";
        } else if ($which == 'table_3'){
            $sql = "SELECT item3 FROM daya.blahblah3"; 
        }

        $stid = oci_parse($this->db, $sql);        

        $list = array();

        while ($list = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) {
            $list[] = $list;
            var_dump($list); // this outputs the correct array I need, but cant bring it to front correctly into dropdown
        }


        if (!@oci_execute($stid)) {
            $error = oci_error($stid);

            throw new Exception($error['message']);
        } 

        oci_execute($stid);

    }
```

Here is the jQuery; the `response` console log is only the flag (`which`) variable I am sending with the `get` request which determines which table to query via a user scenerio. the array I need is ommitted...

```
 let which = $(frm).attr("id");

    $.get('dlteopt', {id: which }, function (response) { 

       console.log(response); // this just consoles as the $which var no array

       $.each(response, function(index, value) {
         // started logic to append values in option; but no array or obj found/brought in to iterate through, can handle this part if can get array
       });

    });
```

html drop down; just standard HTML select with a placeholder until populated:

```
<select name='agent' id='agent'><option>Loading...</option></select>
```

**what am I doing wrong here?** or missing/forgetting?

---

**Update:** I am stuck on an error on the front-end, below is what `console.log(response)` outputs executed within my `$.get`. The data within the error log is correct; I just can't seem to access it properly... 2D array issue?

---

```
jquery.js:502 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 

'length' in ......
    array(2) {
  ["OSF_ID"]=>
  string(8) "FAI-FSDO"
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["OSF_ID"]=>
    string(8) "FAI-FSDO"
  }
}
array(2) {
  ["OSF_ID"]=>
  string(8) "SAC-FSDO"
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["OSF_ID"]=>
    string(8) "SAC-FSDO"
  }
} ..... etc
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the response payload. What is being sent back to jQuery GET request?

Comment: JQuery => php I am just sending the which var which determines which table to ping; 1/3 table options

Comment: Yes, I understand that you're sending the `which` variable. I am asking about what you are seeing in `response`. Please use the Console and Network console to review the Response and Payload. If your not gettign an array or an object, then something is not right in your PHP.

Comment: I suspect the issue is with `var_dump($list);` This will provide Text and not JSON formatted content that JS/jQuery can interpret.

Comment: I am suspecting it is that as well; consoling $list via var dump displays my array in network tab - the correct data is there in preview. Note I have also tried to use .getJSON

Comment: `var_dump()` is not designed for use in this way. Please see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following PHP.

```
public function process($which) {
  if(isset($which)){
    if ($which == 'a_table1'){
      $sql = "SELECT a_table1 FROM data.blah1";
    } else if ($which == 'a_table2'){
      $sql = "SELECT a_table2 FROM data.blah2";
    } else if ($which == 'a_table3'){
      $sql = "SELECT a_table3 FROM data.blah3"; 
    }
 
    $stid = oci_parse($this->db, $sql);
    oci_execute($stid); 
        
    if (!@oci_execute($stid)) {
      $error = oci_error($stid);
      throw new Exception($error['message']);
    }
 
    $myData = array();
    while ($list = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) {
      array_push($myData, $list);
    }
 
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($myData);
 
  } else {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array("error" => "WHICH not assigned"));
  }
}
```

This should then send back JSON Data of the Array.

**Example**

```
[{
  "A_ID":"OJC-FCT"
},{
  "A_ID":"DAL-ATCT"
},{
  "A_ID":"AFF-MIL-TWR"
},{
  "A_ID":"CNO-ATCT"
},{
  "A_ID":"GSN-FCT"
},{
  "A_ID":"CGI-NFCT"
},{
  "A_ID":"NDZ-MIL-TWR"
},{
  "A_ID":"FCS-MIL-TWR"
},{ 
  "A_ID":"LAL-FCT"
},{
  "A_ID":"LNK-ATCT"
},{
  "A_ID":"CHD-FCT"
},{
  "A_ID":"FLG-FCT"
},{
  "A_ID":"MCN-FCT"
},{
  "A_ID":"SKA-MIL-TWR"
}];
```

You can then use this in your Each Loop to build the Options.

```
var which = $(frm).attr("id");
$.get('dlteopt', {id: which }, function (response) { 
  console.log(response);
  $("#agent").html("");
  $.each(response, function(index, value) {
    $("<option>").html(value['A_ID']).appendTo($("#agent"));
  });
});
```

You can also simplify your PHP Output so it's just the result array of items.

```
$myData = array();
while ($list = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) {
  array_push($myData, $list['A_ID']);
}
```

Then you loop will also be simplified.

```
$("#agent").html("");
$.each(response, function(index, value) {
  $("<option>").html(value).appendTo($("#agent"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. so now it appears with this, my $which variable is not posting.. so alas it never makes it to the query.. which consoles fine right before the $.get on jQuery side... strange..

Comment: consoles on front-end; but within PHP, $which is returning as 'false'. i.e.         
    $which = $_GET['id'];

    var_dump($which);

Comment: Within the $.get console log response is still just $which var without array

Comment: You show code `let which = $(frm).attr("id");` yet it does not show where `frm` is defined. Maybe your selector is failing hence you get `null` or `false` value in GET request.

Comment: No; that is consoling fine on the front end... is table name..

Comment: preview tab: 'table1234' (length=9) <-- var debugging fine, but then a 'false' below it.
no line number shown where 'false' is coming from

Comment: what is the result of `var_dump($_GET);`

Comment: false
/opt/www/app/php/routes/data.php:63:string 'table1234' (length=9)
/opt/www/app/php/routes/data.php:64:
array (size=1)
  'id' => string 'table1234' (length=9)

Comment: line 64 ^ is the $_GET dumped... it must be because of the 'false' not sure why the boolean is false if it has value as 'table1234'?

Comment: console.log(response); is only 'false' too, wild....

Comment: @TerryHall something is not making sense. Can you PasteBin your PHP Code and link to it.

Comment: So I am getting the array again on the PHP side via moving the location of my oci_execute - the front-end console.log of 'response' returns this error: "jquery.js:502 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in" (PHP side is fine, no error, correct array and which var returning - seems like it just can't iterate on the front-end)

Comment: @TerryHall sounds like you are still outputting something other than JSON. Again, please Copy/Paste your PHP code to a PasteBin and include it with your reply.

Comment: ok sure; here is the PHP --> https://pastebin.com/HgWjEiJJ

Comment: maybe I need to move the 'header' and 'json_encode' lines somewhere else?

Comment: CRAP, I think I know the problem... it's a 2D array also outputting the column name each time, I just need the values.. perhaps thats it; either loop through the 2D array or regex out only the values

Comment: The issue is that you are outputing data before the header. You can use `var_dump()` for testing but it creates an incorrect syntax for JSON. So once you have the right things coming in and going out, you will want to remove the `var_dump()` portions and set the script to a more production like executation. This is why your payload is not being read by AJAX.

Comment: @TerryHall I updated my answer for the PHP as an example. This helps check `$which` and also addresses the Matrix array. nothing wrong with sending complex data.

Comment: thanks.. the $.each on the front-end still seems to be failing.. maybe the var $which needs to be removed before trying to process the array? the response is now consoling: 'string(9) "whichVAR"
[{"A_ID":"OJC-FCT"},{"A_ID":"DAL-ATCT"},{"A_ID":"AFF-MIL-TWR"},{"A_ID":"CNO-ATCT"},{"A_ID":"GSN-FCT"},{"A_ID":"CGI-NFCT"},{"A_ID":"NDZ-MIL-TWR"},{"A_ID":"FCS-MIL-TWR"},{"A_ID":"LAL-FCT"},{"A_ID":"LNK-ATCT"},{"A_ID":"CHD-FCT"},{"A_ID":"FLG-FCT"},{"A_ID":"MCN-FCT"},{"A_ID":"SKA-MIL-TWR"}'.... etc

Comment: @TerryHall looks like the output is better. Now you just need to update your loop to address the more complex data. Will have an update for you in a moment.

Comment: Even with the updates I am still having difficulties bringing it out on the front-end. 'response' appears to be one huge string with the $which var in it followed by the array; I think I need to omit the $which var somehow from coming back (that was just to determine which table to get from; I dont need it again with the query contents). I have tried JSON stringify and also JSON parse - and still cannot get any iteration through the data

Comment: The error with your update/latest is this: jquery.js:502 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in string(9) "table1234" ... actual array (I think it's snagging on the which var/ table1234 is the which var value before the array)

Comment: I got it by adding these two lines: 
        let rsl = response.match(/\[[^\]]+\]/);
        let lRsp = JSON.parse(rsl); - thanks for tips dude!